# OpenGL Tessellation Shader Not Drawing

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am attempting to tessellate a a sphere, but when I apply the tessellation shaders nothing shows up on screen. After reading quite a bit of literature on this and going through some questions here, I am still unable to figure out what is wrong. There are no errors when linking or loading the shaders either so I am somewhat at a loss.

The shader and drawing code is below.
Thanks.

Vertex

```
#version 410

in vec4 vPosition;
out vec3 Position;

void main()
{
    Position = vPosition.xyz;
}
```

Control

```
#version 410
layout(vertices = 3) out;

in vec3 Position[];
out vec3 tcPosition[];

#define ID gl_InvocationID

void main()
{
    tcPosition[ID] = Position[ID];
    if(ID == 0) {
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 3.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 2.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 2.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 2.0;
    }
}
```

Evaluation

```
#version 410
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;

in vec3 tcPosition[];
out vec3 tePosition;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

void main()
{
    vec3 p0 = gl_TessCoord.x * tcPosition[0];
    vec3 p1 = gl_TessCoord.y * tcPosition[1];
    vec3 p2 = gl_TessCoord.z * tcPosition[2];
    vec3 tePosition = p0 + p1 + p2;
    gl_Position = vec4(tePosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment

```
#version 410

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Draw Code

```
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 3);
glDrawArrays( GL_PATCHES, 0, sphere.vertexNumber );
```